# How to add a sound effect when player collides with object?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hey so I am trying to perform a sound when the player hits the object from the top but isn't working at all, I have the same exact code with other objects and work perfectly just this one don't. Any idea what can it be?

```
class MonsterNode: GameObjectNode {

var monsterType: MonsterType!
let monsterSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("MONSTER.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)

override func collisionWithPlayer(player: SKNode) -> Bool {



    if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 {

        runAction(monsterSound, completion: {
        })

        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: player.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: 450.0)

       self.removeFromParent()


    } else if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 0 {


        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -player.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: -450.0)
        player.hidden = true


    }


    return false
}
```

Comment: wait for complition = true

Comment: still not working @user3351949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to play a sound in self and immediately you are removing self from parent. So try this ,

```
    if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 {

    runAction(monsterSound, completion: { 
           self.removeFromParent()
    })

    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: player.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy: 450.0)
```